# Apache Error 98

Tags: networking, server, apache2

Whenever I boot up Apache, this error occurs:

```
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
```

I've dug around the forums, and found the methods used to view all processes using port 80, such as:

```
lsof -i | grep http
```

and

```
lsof -i | grep :80
```

and then kill them. For some bizarre reason, nothing comes up when I run these checks, and even without the "grep", i still cannot find anything. I've tried reinstalling apache, including purging all the files.

Answer (score 0):

Invoke `lsof -i:80` as *root* and you will see which processes using port 80.